# Merge sort implementation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

I have implemented a Merge sort in Python 3, and it works well. If anything needs to be improved, I would appreciate the criticism.

```
def merge_sort(nums):

    if len(nums) == 1:                                  
        return

    middle_index = len(nums) // 2

    left_half = nums[:middle_index]
    right_half = nums[middle_index:]

    merge_sort(left_half)
    merge_sort(right_half)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while i<len(left_half) and j<len(right_half):
        if left_half[i] < right_half[j]:
            nums[k] = left_half[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            nums[k] = right_half[j]
            j = j + 1

        k = k + 1

    while i<len(left_half):
        nums[k] = left_half[i]
        k = k + 1
        i = i + 1       

if __name__ == "__main__":

   nums = [-3,-2,-1,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3]
   merge_sort(nums)
   print(nums)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I'm going to talk about is in the `merge_sort` function

### General

```
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
```

Can be defined as

`i = j = k = 0`

---

You should always leave spaces between operators as per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules

`i<len(left_half)` should be `i < len(left_half)`

---

Use `x += y` instead of `x = x + y`

---

*In my opinion*, I think using short and concise names such as `mid` or `middle` instead of `middle_index` would be better. If you don't wish to, you can leave it as it!

---

Use [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

---

Add [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

---

### Bug

Your function only takes into account the `left_half` of the array, and ignores what's left in the `right_half`

For example, if `nums` array was `[3, 9, 0]`, The array would be `[0, 3, 0]`

This would happen as

`merge_sort([3])` which won't change the `left_half`
`merge_sort([9, 0])` which would make the `right_half` as `[0, 9]`

Then,

```
left_half = [3]
right_half = [0, 9]

nums = [3, 9, 0]

i = 0
j = 0
k = 0

First, the else statement would be called as 3 > 0.

i = 0
j = 1
k = 1

nums = [0, 9, 0]

Next, the if statement would be called as 3 < 9

i = 1
j = 1
k = 2

nums = [0, 3, 0]

Now, the while loop will terminate as i = len(left_side)

Then, while i < len(left_side) would immediately terminate as i = len(left_side)
```

Did you notice? `right_side` still has one element `9` waiting to be traversed, but it never will be.

To fix that, add the following to the end of the function

```py
while j < len(right_half):
    nums[k] = right_half[j]
    j += 1
    k += 1
```

---

### Improvement

Now, instead of using a `while` loop at all, you can just use `a[k:] = left_half[i:] + right_half[j:]` to replace both the loops! This is true because one half must be empty and the other half must have the length of `n - k`.

---

### Performance

If you are using this function in real time with an array of a really large size, this won't work efficiently.

`len` takes quite a bit of time. To make it even faster, use a parameter `length` which would be the length of the array

---

The final implementation of the function:

```py
from typing import List, Any

def merge_sort(nums: List[Any], length: int) -> None:
    """ Uses Merge Sort to sort an array """

    # Base case
    if length == 1:
        return

    mid = length // 2

    left, right = mid, length - mid

    left_half, right_half = nums[:mid], nums[mid:]

    merge_sort(left_half, left)
    merge_sort(right_half, right)

    i = j = k = 0

    while i < left and j < right:
        if left_half[i] < right_half[j]:
            nums[k] = left_half[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            nums[k] = right_half[j]
            j += 1

        k += 1

    nums[k:] = left_half[i:] + right_half[j:]
```

*Note:* `Any` in `typing` means any datatype is allowed. The function can sort any datatype that is comparable with another element of the same datatype.

Comment: Why is `mid` better than `middle` or `mid_point`?

Comment: `middle` would work as well, but not `middle_index` or `mid_point`. I think the sizes are too big, but that's just my opinion!

Answer (score 0):

For one you could change your code to non-recursive. Lists in python and recursion don't mix well. In other words, what you did might work fine, but it could work a bit better.